# Responsive email template with html and css

Tags: html, css, gmail

How do I make a responsive email template using HTML and CSS? Gmail is not supporting my media queries.

Media queries am using are below:

```
@media all and (max-width:599px){}
@media (max-width:767px){}
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px){}
```

Comment: In sending emails through Gmail it's already responsive, you don't need to responsive the contents. whether you use HTML or CSS or bootstrap

Comment: How did you know it wasn't supported, can you show us your progress in your code ?

Comment: have you checked https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/css ?

Comment: I know because I do that. you can simply use HTML pages. Gmail is not supporting media queries